# JavaScript promise trouble

Tags: javascript, function, promise, resolve

Here's the function:

```
    function load_img(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, rejected) => {

            const img = new Image();
            img.height = 250;
            img.src = url;
            document.body.append(img);
            img.addEventListener("load", () => {
                resolve("LOL");
            });
            img.addEventListener("error", () => {
                rejected();
            });

        });
    }
```

Here's the function call:

```
        load_img(url1)
        .then((mes) => {
            console.log(mes);
            return load_img(url2);
        })
        .then((mes) => {
            load_img(url3);
            console.log(mes);
        })
        .catch(() => console.log("Some error"))
```

I can't understand why should I use in the first **then** *return* before the function, function has already return promise in its body, but when we use it without return in **then**, second **then** won't get any value, which is stated in the resolve().

Please, help me out!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mes` argument in your 2nd `.then()` comes from the return value of the first `.then()` handler.  If you don't return anything from that first `.then()` handler, then you don't get any resolved value in the 2nd `.then()` handler and `mes` will be `undefined`.

Plus, the 2nd `.then()` handler will only "wait" for the `load_img(url2)` to resolve if you return its promise from within the first `.then()` handler.  This is how you properly chain promises.

---

Perhaps you're just using this code for testing, but you do not have to load your two images in sequence since the 2nd one does not depend upon the first one.  You could load them in parallel and use `Promise.all()` to know when they are both done.